# подсчет действий

Tags: база-данных

в бд есть таблица в которую записываются данные действий юзеров. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как правильно написать код в action.php или в phpmyadmin чтобы подсчитывалось общее количество взаимодействий конкретного user_id с code_id

Comment: `COUNT(code_id) GROUP BY user_id`. Посчитать в подзапросе и добавить к основной таблице.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно подробнее. (Посчитать в подзапросе  и добавить к основной таблице) это как сделать? Вернее где и что прописать надо? Заранее спасибо.